# python 3.4 list index attribute throwing error

Tags: python, indexing

SO I get the error below when I run my code,

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\scanned\als course\12 15 14 the al project\index errot.py", line 80, in <module>
    sym_index = sym_list.index(y)
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'index'
>>>
```

I am pretty new to python and I "thought" I had declared the list properly and lists have the index attribute? I just don't understand what is wrong any help would be appreciated ALSO I hope I have made a better job of formatting this question

a subset of the data

```
    2015-08-04 02:14:05.249392,AA,0.0193103612,0.0193515212,0.0249713335,30.6542480634,30.7195875454,39.640763021,0.2131498442,29.0406746589,13524.5347810182,89,57,99
2015-08-04 02:14:05.325113,AAPL,0.0170506271,0.0137941891,0.0105915637,27.0670313481,21.8975963326,16.8135861893,-19.0986405157,-23.2172064279,21.5647072302,33,26,75
2015-08-04 02:14:13.596026,YUM,0.0150960249,0.0096451121,0.0059497165,23.9641966195,15.3111408421,9.4448821537,-36.1082656547,-38.3136615938,6.1077315656,10,11,70
2015-08-05 01:00:01.578356,AA,0.0195344666,0.0197647353,0.0216936719,31.0100044039,31.375544675,34.4376364665,1.178781745,9.7594856861,727.9298290159,83,53,98
2015-08-05 01:00:01.653702,AAPL,0.0182801429,0.0153930649,0.0129012765,29.0188272234,24.4357329651,20.4801414799,-15.7935199208,-16.1877341304,2.4960503525,55,30,69
2015-08-05 01:00:11.685967,YUM,0.015053783,0.0095630245,0.0045548817,23.8971396792,15.1808306936,7.2306505541,-36.4742772674,-52.3698623612,43.5802606239,11,10,74
2015-08-06 01:00:01.580982,AA,0.016405504,0.0187336551,0.0138878945,26.0429302344,29.7387555321,22.0463490932,14.1912805682,-25.8666050455,-282.2711130351,50,69,35
2015-08-06 01:00:01.657591,AAPL,0.0177744137,0.0123407978,0.0155526393,28.2160070183,19.590409183,24.6890494178,-30.5698741487,26.0262059213,-185.1367781062,97,9,44
2015-08-06 01:00:14.071073,YUM,0.0134016613,0.009754587,0.0046291687,21.2744777757,15.4849268147,7.3485774914,-27.2135984817,-52.543673087,93.07874011,19,12,83
2015-08-07 01:00:02.111758,AA,0.0167336443,0.0195330063,0.0157903576,26.5638368026,31.0076862614,25.0664156097,16.7289442857,-19.1606384353,-214.5358494121,42,79,34
2015-08-07 01:00:02.426008,AAPL,0.0172853837,0.01222536,0.0159302942,27.4396959903,19.4071573379,25.2885580713,-29.2734243675,30.3053179346,-203.525018304,96,10,35
2015-08-07 01:00:20.003695,YUM,0.0113498677,0.007539233,0.0090156499,18.0173564022,11.9681613499,14.3119005831,-33.5742653767,19.583118615,-158.3277650167,69,8,34
```

the code causing the err

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

num_sym = 100
num_days = 252

sym_list = []
date_list = []
sym_index = 0
date_index = 0




hvabs_tab = [[0 for x in range(num_sym)] for y in range(num_days)]
dates_t = []



def dedupe(items):
    seen = set()
    for item in items:
        if item not in seen:
            yield item
            seen.add(item)

    return item



def parse_ymd(s):

    date_bit = s.split('-')

    long_date = date_bit[0]+":" + date_bit[1]+":"  + date_bit[2]  # formatted 2015:08:05

    #print('y',date_bit[0],'m',date_bit[1],'d',date_bit[2],'all',date_bit)
    #y 2015 m 08 d 04 all ['2015', '08', '04']

    return long_date # formatted 2015:08:05





with open('hvanal2015s.csv') as f:

    f_csv = csv.reader(f)

    for x in f_csv:
        for i,y in enumerate(x):
            if i == 1 :
                sym_list.append(y) # grabbing ALL the symbols shoving them in list

            if i == 0 :
                date_line = str(x[0])
                date_t = date_line.split()
                just_date = parse_ymd(date_t[0])
                date_list.append(just_date) # grabbing ALL dates shoving them in list




    sym_list = dedupe(sym_list)

    date_list = dedupe(date_list)

    print('sym list final',*sym_list)
    print('date list final',*date_list)
    print('---------------------')



    f.seek(0) # resetting the csv iterator to top of file to process the ranks now we have
                  # the lists for sym and dates populated

    for day_data in f_csv:
        for i,y in enumerate(day_data):
            if i == 1 : # found symbol
               sym_index = sym_list.index(y)
               print('y and sym index',y,sym_index)



           # if i == 0 : # found related date 
               #date_index = date_list.index(y)
               # print('y and date index',y,date_index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the defition if `dedupe`:

```
def dedupe(items):
    seen = set()
    for item in items:
        if item not in seen:
            yield item
            seen.add(item)

    return item
```

See the `yield` keyword?  That makes the return value an `generator` (which is iterable), but it isn't a `list`.  You can easily construct a `list` from the generator though by using the builtin `list` callable:

```
sym_list = list(dedupe(sym_list))
```

---

<sup>Also, note that your `dedupe` generator function has a `return` statement, but it doesn't really do anything here other than trick unsuspecting readers of you code into thinking that `dedupe` isn't a generator :-)</sup>

Comment: Hey Mgilson thank you for taking the time to help a noob, I'm going to have to research ALL of what you wrote as I am one of the duped ( geddit) readers of the code which I copied without comprehension. Thanks again a really great assist.